# Google Apps Script error for createAllDayEvent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a google apps script to retrieve event data from a google sheet.

I keep getting this error:
"Exception: The parameters (String,String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createAllDayEvent. (line 21, file "sheets to calendar")."

Any suggestions on the cause of the problem?

```
function sheets_to_calendar(){

var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("x@group.calendar.google.com");
var Title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J1').getValue();
  
var date  = new Date(month + day + ',' + year);
var year = date.getYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;  if(month.toString().length==1){var month = 
'0'+month;}
var day = date.getDate(); if(day.toString().length==1){var day = '0'+day;}
var hour = date.getHours(); if(hour.toString().length==1){var hour = '0'+hour;}
var minu = date.getMinutes(); if(minu.toString().length==1){var minu = '0'+minu;}
var seco = date.getSeconds(); if(seco.toString().length==1){var seco = '0'+seco;}
var date = year+'·'+month+'·'+day+'·'+hour+'·'+minu+'·'+seco;
Logger.log(date);

var description = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F13').getValue();

eventCal.createAllDayEvent(Title, date, {description: "test"});
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Issues:

- As stated in the official documentation, [createAllDayEvent(title,
  date, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-date,-options) accepts a JavaScript `date` object as the second argument, **not** a `string`.
- In your example, you are passing a `string`.

---

To create a date object in javascript you have multiple ways, but since you want to define specific `month`, `date` and `year` you should use this one:

```
var date = new Date(year, month-1, day)
```

Keep in mind that the parameter `month` starts from `0`. If you want to pass `24th of October 2020` you need to do:

```
var date = new Date(2020, 9, 24)
```

---

### Solution:

```
function sheets_to_calendar(){

var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("x@group.calendar.google.com");
var Title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J1').getValue();
var date  = new Date(year, month-1, day);
var description = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F13').getValue();
eventCal.createAllDayEvent(Title, date, {description: description});    
}
```

---

### Minimal reproducible example:

```
function sheets_to_calendar(){

var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
var date  = new Date(2020, 9, 24);
var Title = 'this is a title';
var description = 'this is a description';
event.createAllDayEvent(Title, date, {description: description});  
}
```